# Does the Rayleigh formula apply to electron microscopes or only light microscopes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, microscopy

I am asked to determine the resolving power of both a TEM (transmission electron microscope) and a SEM (scanning electron microscope) and given the Rayleigh formula below.

$$\mathrm{Resolution}=\frac{0.61\lambda}{N.A.}$$
Where $\lambda=0.0039$ nm since the wavelength of an electron is $0.039$ angstroms and $1Å=0.1$ nm.

I am also told that the N.A. the numerical aperture for the TEM is $0.01$

So, $$\mathrm{Resolution} =\frac{0.61(0.0039\, \mathrm{nm})}{0.01}=0.24\, \mathrm{nm}$$

For the SEM I am not given the N.A. but I am told that the resolution is $10$ nm

My problem is if I use the Rayleigh formula  $$\mathrm{Resolution}=\frac{0.61\lambda}{N.A.}=10\, \mathrm{nm}$$ I get $$N.A.=0.0002379$$ Which would imply that the aperture for the SEM is greater than that of TEM since N.A for TEM is $0.01$ and SEM is $0.00023$ $$0.01>0.00023.$$

My problem is that I'm told the greater the aperture (smaller value of aperture) the greater the resolution but as you can see from the equations above this doesn't seem to make sense, The only explanation I can think of is that the Rayleigh formula does not apply to electron microscopes. Any advice would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: The statement that puzzles you is perfectly fine, but only in an ideal case of no aberrations and no electron sub-surface scattering. And these are the effects that limit the resolution of an SEM, even though its N. A. is somewhat higher than 0.0002379. If such troubles are resolved, you can get better resolution, in state-of-the-art SEMs down to few nm scale.